# Which index should I choose?(Mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `f1` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `f2` int(4) NOT NULL default '0',
  `f3` bigint(20) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`f1`)
) TYPE=MyISAM
```

**Query:**

```
select `f1` from table1 where `f2`=123 order by `f3` desc;
```

I want create a "covering index" for this query

```
ALTER TABLE `table1` ADD INDEX (`f2`,`f3`,`f1`);
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE `table1` ADD INDEX (`f2`,`f1`,`f3`);
```

which should I choose?

Comment: I doubt either of them will help you in a significant way.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ  I'm sure useful, but I do not know which is better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one. MySQL can use either index to obtain the result set without needing to read from the actual table. The first index is slightly more efficient because it is not necessary to perform the extra step of re-ordering the rows.

Comment: Yes, the first index requires only a sequential read of that part of the index that matches the WHERE clause without any additional ordering.  It offers the most opportunity for improving the performance of your query.

Answer (score 0):

for you query you need an index on f2 only.

if you a query with a whereclause like "where f1=12 and f2=15", you ***might*** want an index on f1 and f2 too. However, it might be that the primary key will give you results faster, depending on the data and complete query.

you (might) need an index covering the 3 fields if you have queries ranging on the 3 (in the where clause).

in 15 years, I never faced the need to create an index for ordering results only. This operation is quite fast. What is slow is finding the rows (the where clause), and the different set matches (joins).

Now if you are not sure, create both. Do you query and check with explain_plan which one mysql uses. Then drop the other ^^.

Comment: add `f3` to index for avoid filesort,and `f1` to index for covering index. **covering index：** An index that contains (or “covers”) all the data needed to satisfy a query is called a covering index.covering indexes can be a very powerful tool and can dramatically improve performance.

Comment: yeah yeah yeah but non *self* covering indexes and index size make them... double edged swords. As you say, it ***can*** be very powerful, under the *right* conditions. ...which are each 29 of February.